# Subset error when trying to double subset

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
Year Sex   Age       
1991    0     Group1
1991    0     Group2
1991    1     Group1
1991    1     Group2
1992    0     Group1
1992    0     Group2
1992    1     Group1
1992    1     Group2
```

I am trying to subset it into several different subsets,

I used

```
male <- df1[df1$sex == 1, ]
```

But in the second step, when I was trying to use

```
age1male <- male[male$Age == Group1, ]
```

again to further subset it, the outcome becomes messy, many rows of the year appear to be `NA`, and the number in the first column becomes something like `NA.78`, `NA.9` etc, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: `male[male$Age == "Group1", ]` (the double-quotes matter); also, if you're using `attach()` anywhere, don't. it causes more harm than good in the long run.

Comment: @hrbrmstr hi, Thanks! But unfortunately, it still has the same problem when I added the quotes, any other ideas?

Comment: Not without a larger data sample (you can do that by doing something like dput(head(df1, 50))` and putting the output in a code block (lines prefixed with 4 spaces). `50` is arbitrary. Any # that's representative would be good. The output of `sessionInfo()` and `ls.str()` (again, in code blocks) would help, too. A link to the data file is fine if that'd be easier than the `dput()`

Comment: Make sure the column name matches: `male <- df1[df1$Sex == 1,]` (note the capital)

Comment: How about this: `subset(df1, Sex==1 & Age=='Group1')`?

Comment: @EdwardCarney This works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks everyone! I really appreciate your help ,and apologize I didn't use a very good subsample, I will learn to be better in this community!